# Databricks on Apache Spark AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

When attempting to readStream data fron Azure Event Hub with Databricks on Apache Spark I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

The details of the error is as follows:

```
----> 8 ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```

The code is as follows:

```
sparkContext = ""
connectionString = 'Endpoint=sb://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=both4;SharedAccessKey=adfdMyKeyIGBKYBs=;EntityPath=hubv5'
# Source with default settings
connectionString = connectionString

ehConf = {}

ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

streaming_df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()
```

Has anyone come across this error and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be the `sparkContext`, but just `sc`:

```py
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```

P.S. But it's just easier to use built-in Kafka connector with EventHubs - you don't need to install anything, and it's more performant...

Comment: Thanks for reaching out Alex. Can you suggest a Kafka connector?

Comment: Databricks runtimes come with built-in. and here is an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-spark-tutorial#read-from-event-hubs-for-kafka